# How to make linear layout inside pop up view responsive?

Tags: android, kotlin, responsive-design, popupwindow

what I want to do is display a responsive pop up view. What I have now is that the pop up view resizes the original linear layout and it displays very bad on some devices.

This is how the linear layout xml looks like

[layout.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQDDr.png)

and when I run it, this is how it is displayed

[popupView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfAuO.png)

This is the pop up view code:

```
private fun setUpModalProduct() {
        inventoryMovementPopUpView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.modal_inventory_movement,
                null) // inflating popup layout
    val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.40).toInt() // 0.90 = 90% of width size
    val height = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 1).toInt() // 0.90 = 90% of hight size

    inventoryMovementPopUp = PopupWindow(inventoryMovementPopUpView,
            width,  //width value
            height,  //height value
            true) // Creation of popup

    inventoryMovementPopUp!!.animationStyle = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog
    inventoryMovementPopUp!!.showAtLocation(inventoryMovementPopUpView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)

    inventoryMovementPopUp!!.isOutsideTouchable = false
    inventoryMovementPopUp!!.isFocusable = false
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 val width = 600 //LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 val height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

And on your layout xml parent

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: thanks for the relpy. It improves the view on the emulator, but on phisycal device it still is not working